# concise way to build an object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iteration

The following code is working as expected but I'm wondering if there's a way to use `Object.assign`, or some other approach, to build the `derivedData` object so that it doesn't need to be initialized as an empty object and then populated in a subsequent step.

```
const data = [
  {"period": "2021-05-01", "quantity": "28"},
  {"period": "2021-06-01", "quantity": "42"},
  {"period": "2021-07-01", "quantity": "66"}
];

const derivedData = {};
data.forEach(o => {
  derivedData[o.period] = o.quantity
});

console.log(data);
console.log(derivedData);
```

Expected output of `derivedData`:

```
{
  "2021-05-01": "28",
  "2021-06-01": "42",
  "2021-07-01": "66"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the handy [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) function. It takes a list of key-value pairs and constructs an object from the list. For example:

```javascript
> Object.fromEntries([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

In your scenario, we can construct these key-value pairs by simply doing using array.map() on your data. This is what a complete solution looks like:

```js
const data = [
  {"period": "2021-05-01", "quantity": "28"},
  {"period": "2021-06-01", "quantity": "42"},
  {"period": "2021-07-01", "quantity": "66"}
];

const derivedData = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(({ period, quantity }) => [period, quantity])
);

console.log(data);
console.log(derivedData);
```

Answer (score 4):

While it technically still would initialize it as an empty object, one could build `derivedData` with one call to [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It is similar to `forEach()` except that the first argument of the callback function is an accumulator variable, that needs to be returned at the end of the function. See the snippet below for a demonstration.

```js
const data = [
  {"period": "2021-05-01", "quantity": "28"},
  {"period": "2021-06-01", "quantity": "42"},
  {"period": "2021-07-01", "quantity": "66"}
];

const derivedData = data.reduce((accumulator, o) => {
  accumulator[o.period] = o.quantity;
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log('derivedData: ', derivedData);
```

You may find [these functional exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/) interesting.

Good job using `const` for variables that don't need to be re-assigned, and using common spacing conventions for modern JavaScript.